# AngularJS & Bootstrap UI: Toggle Button State Issue with Angular directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I make my first steps with AngularJS and use a toggle button (bootstrap ui) and directives to show or hide an input:

- Yes: Show or Hide a Row with the default value 0.00
- No: Clear an Input

It works (Pls see my [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bO3yUxKFmMJG5B8v4CIY?p=preview)), but If the user type in some value, the toggle-Button for "Yes" will not remain active. I've tried a lot, what is going wrong?

**HTML**

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'0.00'">Yes</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="''">No</label>
</div>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input ng-model="radioModel" ng-show="radioModel">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Nobody an idea or tip? Thank you

Comment: You have the same ng-model for radios and for the input.